# What does ./configure do?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mysql

I am trying to install MySQL on Snow Leopard. The commands go something like this:

```
cd mysql
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

However, I am not able to get past the configure step because I get this message:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

My question is:

What is the `./configure` step trying to do? Is it a command that I need to have installed? Or is it something that is supposed to be included in the MySQL package?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to build MySQL from source rather than just downloading a DMG archive from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and using the installer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

configure is a script which checks to make sure your system has the proper dependencies in order to compile mysql from source.

This error message is simply saying the file named "configure" is not in the present directory (the . stands for the current directory).  Make sure that there is a file named "configure" in the directory you are presently at before you try to do "./configure".  You are most likely in the wrong directory or the package you downloaded is incomplete.

You will often also have to manually configure packages before compiling too.  Make sure that there isn't a readme somewhere.

Comment: To add to the fact that the dot and the slash (./) is to explicitly state that the configure script is in the current directory, just writing configure doesn't work because the current path is not searched for executable commands, for security purposes.

Answer (score -1):

to add something to Daisetsu's anwer:

When downloading source try also checking for md5 hashes (md5 checksum). These strings are unique when applied to a file, much like a fingerprint. That way you can check if the file you downloaded is complete or not, and should be available on sites like MySQL's.

On unix based systems, that would be, through shell

```
myuser$ openssl md5 source.tar.gz
```

This will spare you from potential headaches due to corrupted file downloads.

While we are at that, maybe you'd take the easy road and download, configure and install MySQL through port:

```
myuser$ sudo port install mysql5
```

And that would be it. Application binaries should be available at `/opt/local/bin`.

Cheers.

Comment: "I am trying to install MySQL on snow leopard". Maybe it's just easier to install it via port. You can also try [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) for more extended definitions, if you want to.